# Usage of pcl::CropHull

Tags: point-cloud-library, pcl

Hello I am looking for a way to find out points/indices of point cloud which lie within a set of pre-defined polygon points/indices.

My Input would be either of the following.

1. Set of indices of the cloud forming a 2D polygon. Eg : 21480, 4491, 20399, 19034, 21322, 5240, 5870, 21480
2. Set of coordinates(x,y,z) which correspond to the above indices in the cloud.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seXqk.png)

Answer (score 1):

May I politelly suggest you the documentation [pcl::CropHull](https://docs.w3cub.com/point_cloud_library/classpcl_1_1_crop_hull)

In your case. the methods:
`setHullCloud (PointCloudPtr points)`
`setCropOutside (bool crop_outside)`
and then
`filter (PointCloud &output)`

should do the job.

If this did not answer your problem please be more specific to which problems you are exactly facing when using pcl::CropHull (with code if possible)